# How to get LogicMonitor data into grafana?

Tags: jenkins, jmeter, performance-testing, grafana

I want to run load & performance tests and monitor them via [Grafana](https://grafana.net/).  I have the [JMeter Dashboard](https://grafana.net/dashboards/1152) and JenkinsCI Dahsboard setup and running, so I can see the client side data in real time.  This is a good setup.

What's next, is trying to combine the Server Side Data concurrently with the Client Side data at the same time, within the same dashboard. I have a LogicMonitor installation for the Cloud Instances on AWS.

Does anyone know how to do this?

Suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it turns out, you cannot do this.  Logic Monitor Does not use InnoDB for format, so, it's not an easy port over to the data.